# On the inclusion homomorphism $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism

This question is about the group homomorphism $i: \mathbb Z\to\mathbb Q$ given by $m\mapsto m$.

1) Is the following proof of the fact that the arrow $i$ in $\mathbf {Ab}$ is  epic correct? Let $h,h':\mathbb Q\to G$ be group homomorphisms. Suppose $h\circ i=h'\circ i$. Then for all $n$, $h(i(n))=h'(i(n))$, i.e., $h(n)=h'(n)$ since $i(n)=n$. Thus $i$ is epic.

2) The group homomorphism $i: \mathbb Z\to\mathbb Q$ given by $m\mapsto m$ is known to be a monic that is not split in $\mathbf {Ab}$. Why is that? Assume that it is split monic. Then there is a group homo $l:\mathbb Q\to \mathbb Z$ such that $l\circ i=1_\mathbb Z$. What does this contradict to? For any $m\in \mathbb Z$ this says that $l(i(m))=m$, i.e., $l(m)=m$. So if $l$ exists, then it $l\restriction_\mathbb Z:\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z$ must be given by $m\mapsto m$. So I guess the statement that needs to be proved is that there does not exist a group homomorphism $l:\mathbb Q\to\mathbb Z$ such that $l(m)=m$ for all $m\in\mathbb Z$. How to show that?

Comment: See also [this older answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63018/showing-two-ring-homomorphisms-that-agree-on-the-integers-must-agree-on-the-rati/63022#63022).

Comment: In $\mathbf{Ab}$, all epimorphisms are surjective: if $f\colon B\to A$ is an epimorphism, then considering the canonical projection $\pi A\to A/f(B)$ and the zero map $A\to A/f(B)$ gives $\pi\circ f= z\circ f$, and since $f$ is an epimorphism, then $\pi = z$. But this means that $\pi(a)=\mathbf{0}$ for all $a\in A$, and hence that $f(B)=A$; i.e., $f$ is onto. The claim is also true for $\mathbf{Group}$ (and even $\mathbf{FinGroup}$), though this proof of course does not work in those cases.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Does this have a direct relation to the question, or is it just a separate useful piece of information?

Comment: You are asserting that a certain map is an epimorphism in $\mathbf{Ab}$: it isn’t, because in $\mathbf{Ab}$ all epimorphisms are surjective, and the map you have is not surjective. The assertion about $\mathbf{Group}$ and $\mathbf{FinGroup}$ is not directly related, but it’s worth mentioning because otherwise people are sometimes fooled into thinking that a map in $\mathbf{Group}$ is an epimorphism if and only if the normal closure of the image is the whole group (thinking about the same argument as for Abelian groups); and that is incorrect.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Indeed, while having trivial kernel is equivalent to be monic in $\mathbf{Grp}$, having trivial cokernel is not equivalent to being epic. In fact, a homomorphism has trivial cokernel if and only if its image is a contranormal subgroup of the codomain, and proper contranormal retracts (which must correspond to semidirect products) do exist. For example, $\{e, (1 2)\}$ is a contranormal retract in $S_5$ (the complementary normal subgroup being $A_5$).

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang: Given that my dissertation concerned, inter alia, nonsurjective epimorphisms in varieties of groups, I am well aware of this. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your argument only shows that if $h\circ i=h’\circ i$, then $h(n)=h’(n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. However, you need to show that $h(q)=h’(q)$ for all $q\in\mathbb{Q}$. In order to do that, you will need to use the *multiplicative* structure of $\mathbb{Q}$, as this does not follow from just the additive structure (the canonical projection $\pi\colon\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ and the zero map $z\colon\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ satisfy $\pi\circ i = z\circ i$, but $\pi\neq z$; note that these are group homomorphisms, but not ring homomorphisms). That is, the embedding is **not** an epimorphism of abelian groups.

   To complete the argument and show that it is an epimorphism in the category of **rings** you need to be careful. If you assume that rings always have a $1$ and that ring homomorphisms map $1$ to $1$, then you can use the fact that under those circumstances, units must be mapped to units and multiplicative inverses to multiplicative inverses (which are unique), so that you will have for every $n\neq 0$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$
   $$h\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = h(n^{-1}) = h(n)^{-1} = h’(n)^{-1} = h’(n^{-1}) = h’\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
   and then conclude that if $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$, $q\neq 0$, then
   $$h\left(\frac{p}{q}\right) = h(p)h(q^{-1}) = h’(p)h’(q^{-1}) = h’\left(\frac{p}{q}\right).$$

   However, if you do not assume that rings must have a $1$ or that maps between rings must send $1$ to $1$, the claim is *still* true; you can see a proof using a zigzag in [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63018/showing-two-ring-homomorphisms-that-agree-on-the-integers-must-agree-on-the-rati/63022#63022). Note that the latter proof in fact does not even use the *additive* structures of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$; it only concerns the multiplicative structure and multiplicative maps. It is a proof that the embedding is an epimorphism in the category semigroups, where we view both $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ as multiplicative semigroups.
2. Suppose $f\colon\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Z}$ is a group homomorphism. For every $n\gt 0$, we have that $\frac{1}{n}$ added to itself $n$ times equals $1$, hence
   $$f(1) = f\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n}\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).$$
   If $f(1)=a\in\mathbb{Z}$, then this tells you that for every $n\gt 0$ there exists a $b\in\mathbb{Z}$ (namely, $f(\frac{1}{n})$) such that $nb = a$. (Here, $nb$ means “$b$ added to itself $n$ times”, but this agrees with the usual multiplication of integers). But this means that $a$ is divisible by $n$, and this must hold for *all* natural numbers $n\gt 0$. The only integer with this property is $0$, so we must have $f(1)=0$. In particular, we cannot have $f(m)=m$ for all $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ if $f$ is an additive map. (In fact, you must have $f(x)=0$ for all $x$, since by the above you conclude that every integer must map to $0$, and hence every rational $\frac{p}{q}$ must map to a $q$-torsion element... and the only such element is $0$).

Answer (score 4):

The inclusion $\mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ is not epic in $\mathbf{Ab}$, but it is epic in $\mathbf{Ring}$ as well as in the category of torsion-free abelian groups.

Also, there is no nonzero homomorphism from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$, because the image of any rational number would have to be an integer that is divisible by every nonzero integer, and no nonzero integer is divisible by any integer with a larger absolute value.

Comment: Then at which point does my "proof" of $\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Q$ being epic in $\mathbf{Ab}$ go wrong?

Comment: @user634426 The error is the word "Thus" in the last sentence. To conclude that $i$ is epic, you'd need to show $h(x)=h'(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb Q$, not just for $x\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Also, I don't understand why the image of $1$ would have to be divisible by every nonzero integer. According to what I wrote in the question, the image of $1$ is $1$, and it's not divisible by every nonzero integer. But I think [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2044698/634426) applies to prove that there is only zero homomorphism.

Comment: @AndreasBlass So to prove the correct statement it remains to show that $h(x)=h'(x)$ for $x=p/q$ where $p/q$ is in lowest terms. We have $h(p/q)=h(p)h(q^{-1})=h(p)h(q)^{-1}=h'(p)h'(q)^{-1}=h'(p)h'(q^{-1})=h'(p/q)$ -- is it how one proves it?

Comment: @user634426 So in the newest comment you're talking about ring homomorphisms. What you wrote has an obvious typo ($q^{-q}$) and uses without proof that $h(q^{-1})=h(q)^{-1}$ (and likewise for $h'$). Otherwise, it looks good.

Comment: Right, I should have included more words to specify that $h$ is a ring homomorphism now. It appears to me that the statement $h(q^{-1})=h(q)^{-1}$ is obvious because $h(q)h(q^{-1})=h(qq^{-1})=h(1)=1$. As for the second question of mine, I guess one could use that the image of a divisible group is divisible and there is only one divisible subgroup of the integers - the zero subgroup.

Comment: The inclusion is also an epi in the category of monoids, if you only look at the multiplicative structure.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\Ab}{\mathrm{Ab}}$
$\newcommand{\Mod}[1]{\,(\mathrm{mod}\,#1)}$

Regarding $(1)$, the fail in your proof is that you are assuming that $h(n) = h'(n)$ for every integer $n$ implies $h(r)=h'(r)$ for every rational $r$. For an example that this need not hold, you can quickly check that the maps
$$h:\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}/\langle 1\rangle \\ x\mapsto x \Mod{1}$$
and
$$h':\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}/\langle\textstyle{1}\rangle \\ x\mapsto 2x\Mod{1}$$
are homomorphisms satisfying $h(n)=0=h'(n)$ for every integer $n$. However, the maps are clearly not equal, since $h(1/2)=1/2$ but $h'(1/2) = 0$.

Comment: What is $\langle 1\rangle$? Is it $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: @user634426 The subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$ generated by $1$. Indeed it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.