Proof for non existence of a quotient group of $\mathbb{(Q,+)}$,which is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z},+)$.
Consider the following statements:

I. There exists a proper subgroup $G$ of $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ such that $\mathbb{Q}/G$ is a finite group.
II. There exists a subgroup $G$ of $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ such that $\mathbb{Q}/G$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$.

The above question was asked in $\text{GATE 2024}$.
Statement (I) is not true as  $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ has no proper subgroup of finite index. (I have a proper proof of this statement by way of contradiction.)
For statement (II), I found from site search that this statement is also not true. Reason is simply given that $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ is a divisible group and hence every quotient group of $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ is divisible. Therefore, there does not exists a subgroup $G$ of $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ such that $\mathbb{Q}/G$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$.
Question: Is there any other method to show that the statement (II) is not true, which is independent of divisibility. Because my concepts of divisibility of groups are weak.
I tried to think in this way: Since each non identity element of $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$ is of infinite order and my intuition says that each element of a quotient group of $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ is of finite order, therefore both can not be isomorphic. I am not sure that my intuition is correct and if it is true then how can I prove the above intuition.
Kindly help me.

If $Q$ is a quotient of $G$, then there is a surjective homomorphism form $G $ to $Q$. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2044698/976076

Hint: Proceed by way of contradiction. Prove that there is a subgroup $H$ of $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ such that $(\mathbb{Q}, +) = G \oplus H$.

@ghc1997 $\mathbb{Q}$ is not quotient of $G$ and I am unable to understand how this link address my problem.Kindly help me.

@AndreasCaranti Sorry,I am unable to understand.Kindly help me.Thank you.

The $Q$ and $G$ in my comment are just two arbitrary groups

@ghc1997 Got it.

I am writing the answer using the link provided by @ghc1997.Suppose that there were an isomorphism $f : \mathbb{Q}/G\to \mathbb{Z}$. Then there exists some $q +G\in \mathbb{Q}/G$ such that $f(q+G) = 1$. But then, $x = f(q/2+G)$ is an integer satisfying
$$2x = x+x = f(q/2+G) + f(q/2+G) = f(q/2 + q/2+G) = f(q+G)= 1,$$
which is impossible. Therefore there is no such $f$.

This is not different from the divisibility argument.

@АрсенийКряжев Because we are using the fact that 1 is not divisible by 2 in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Yes, there is nothing special about 2.
